# TimeZone changed while converting string to Date

Tags: ios, swift

When I'm changing date(which is in string form) to Date form,Then timezone change IST to UTC.Because of that I'm not getting notification

My code is :

```
@IBAction func datePickerDidSelectNewDate(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let selectedDate = sender.date
    let dateStr = Date().currentTimeZoneDate(date: selectedDate as NSDate)
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr)
    let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    delegate?.scheduleNotification(at: date!)
}
```

In my code, I'm getting `selectedDate` is in UTC time zone.So I have converted it into currentTimeZone.But when I change String form to Date,means `dateStr`to `date` it again convert to UTC timeZone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `currentTimeZoneDate`? This seems a deep misunderstanding of Date. Dates a never "in a time zone." Dates are an absolute point in time. All observers, no matter where they are, should agree on when a given Date occurs (ignoring relativistic effects).

You should configure `UIDatePicker` with the time zone you want it to represent. The default is `localTimeZone`, which always is the current time zone at the point that this action is called (so `sender.date` has already been adjusted). If you want it to represent some other time zone, change `UIDatePicker.timeZone`. Don't mess with the Date. Definitely don't convert it to a string and back.

It's unclear what `scheduleNotification(at:)` does, or what the final goal is. `NSUserNotification` by default will adjust all of its delivery dates if the time zone changes. If you don't want this (if you want to maintain the precise instant that the user selected, rather than the nominal time they selected), then you should set `deliveryTimeZone` on the notification (generally to `NSTimeZone.default`, which is a non-updating version of "the current time zone").

Comment: Thank for help.I'm just trying to implement local notification but by default it taking  selectedDate in UTC timezone.So I have done all this thing just for get current time zone.

Comment: `selectedDate` cannot be "in UTC". Dates are an absolute point in time; they don't have time zones (or days, or years, or anything else related to a calendar). If you mean that the nominal time that the user selected is being interpreted as UTC, and you want it to be something else, then set the date picker's time zone so that it creates the date correctly. The default behavior, though, is for date pickers to use the local time zone, so this is very surprising.

Comment: A very common mistake is that people do something like `print(selectedDate)` and see "UTC" or "+00:00" or whatever in there and think that means it's "in UTC." This is not true. Dates do not have time zones. They just are displayed that way in their description to make them easier to read for humans.

Answer (score 1):

Swift's `Date` type (and also its Objective-C `NSDate`) doesn't have any notion of TimeZone in itself. It's just a simple timestamp. This means that if you set a timezone to a UIDatePicker, you can use its date as it is in that timezone without a need of converting it.

More explanation: when you `po date` in a debugger console, the debugger just select the `UTC` timezone as a presentation of the printing date. Its behavior doesn't related to the Date instance.